# Why “ifconfig” docker command responds "bash: ifconfig: command not found" on Windows?

Tags: windows, docker, networking, ifconfig

I installed docker on my windows PC.

I opened console and typed `docker ps`. That command works properly. Next I tried to execute command if config but it was not found:

```
$ ifconfig
bash: ifconfig: command not found
```

Is it because of Windows ?

### P.S.

Command `docker network ls`  also works properly

Comment: Here's a reference with all available commands, it doesn't include ifconfig.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finding current TCP/IP network configuration values doesn't have nothing to do with docker, those applications coming with your os.

- for windows `ipconfig` -> [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipconfig)
- for mac `ifconfig` -> [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ifconfig)
- for linux use `ip` related commands for ex: to get the ip address `ip
  addr show`

*NOTE: in linux ifconfig might work but its deprecated.*

more about `ifconfig vs ip` you can read in this [blog](https://p5r.uk/blog/2010/ifconfig-ip-comparison.html)

Comment: what is your os?

Comment: OpenMediaVault (Debian-based) on VBox. Seems just like my docker-container doesn't come with those tools.